# Method for deriving a string from an enum

Tags: objective-c, c

I've been wondering if there's an elegant way to derive a string from an enum in Objective-C or vanilla C. I'm currently using a switch statement like so:

```
switch (self.requestType) 
{
    case MSListRequest:
        serverRequestType = @"List";
        break;
    case MSDetailsRequest:
        serverRequestType = @"Details";
        break;
    case MSPurchaseRequest:
        serverRequestType = @"PurchaseVolume";
        break;
}
```

I'm curious if there's a cleaner way to derive strings than this.

-edit:
I'm also using the same enum elsewhere to interface to a different system that needs to map the same enums to a different set of strings.

Comment: Do you consider macros cleaner? And how much preprocessor power are you willing to use?

Comment: I'd rather not do it with macros, I generally dislike using the preprocessor unless there's no other efficient way of doing things.

Comment: You might want to read through [this](http://iphone-dev-tips.alterplay.com/2009/11/convert-objective-c-typedef-enum-to-its.html).

Answer (score 0):

There's no real *nice* way to do this.  A very simple way is to create an array:

```
NSString *const ENUM_NAMES[] = {
    @"List", @"Details", @"PurchaseVolume", ...
};
```

There are alternatives that use macros and some simple preprocessor hacks to define both the names and the enum itself from the same source.  However, the resulting code is more difficult to read.

```
// some_enum.def
X(List),
X(Details),
X(PurchaseVolume)

// some_enum.h
enum {
    #define X(x) x
    #include "some_enum.def"
    #undef X
};

// some_enum.c
char const *const ENUM_STRING[] = {
    #define X(x) #x
    #include "some_enum.def"
    #undef X
};
```

I'm not sure of the best way to generate an NSString from the preprocessor, whether you can just stick an `@` in it or if it's better to use `(NSString *)CFSTR(x)`.

When I need a bunch of code like this, I write a Python script to generate the code from a text file -- it generates GPerf output for converting strings to enum, and it generates the code for converting enum to string as well.  Plain old C doesn't do reflection.

Comment: Mapping from the enum to a const array was my first thought as well, but it didn't seem particularly elegant or easy to maintain. Considering there's only 3 or 4 values for the enums I'm doing this with, I'll probably just stick to the switch method unless someone comes up with an elegantly simple way to handle this.

Comment: @Shinohara: That's exactly the point: There is no *elegantly simple* way to do this.  Not in C.